# A question about pad footprint

Tags: pcb, pins, pad

I want to make a PCB for the pins of this unit:

[image]

So the pins at the bottom of the unit will be soldered to a custom PCB. In the bottom it is shown that the pin diameter is 0.5mm. When making PCB pads for these pins to be soldered to, what should be the hole diameter of the pads? I was planning to make 0.6mm but don't know if there's a standard.

Comment: Does the part come with a recommended PCB land pattern with recommended hole size?

Comment: If the holes are plated-through, how thick is this plating?  Then there are two "sides" to this so the hole must be oversized by twice this amount at least.  Give yourself some wiggle-room also; nothing worse than making the hole too tight and requiring 20 minutes to install each one.

Answer (score 1):

There's not a hard and fast rule, it's a trade off.

a) You need to make your holes big enough to include some tolerance, the PCB fab for example will have a +- tolerance on their drills.
b) Make the hole too big, and the part will be able to move about during assembly which can be a pain.
c) Make the hole too big, and the annular ring (the difference between the pad and the hole) will be too small
d) If the fit is very tight, this can make desoldering difficult (which may or may not be a concern)
e) A tight fit might also make inserting the part harder

As has been said you should check the manufacturers' datasheet for a recommended landing pattern, I'd probably go for around 0.7mm personally. Consider that 0.1mm really isn't that much, it's the 'thickness of a human hair'. It's worth bearing in mind that for most applications, having too loose a fit is far preferable to having to manually enlarge some holes.